# Color scheme used by Colorize?

Tags: image-processing, color

The `Colorize` function is often used to display the results produced by `MorphologicalComponents`:

```
i = ImageTake[
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], {1, -1, 10}, {1, -1, 10}];
b = Binarize[i, .5];
mc = MorphologicalComponents[b];
Colorize[mc]
```

[image: mandrill taken]

The colors represent the integer index values of each foreground component, so the  magenta area is 2, the black background is 0, 42 is browney-orange, 19 is violet, and - well, my question is, what is this color scheme?

I'm working on images like the following, to try to understand morphological images, but a legend-type approach might be better:

```
Show[
 ArrayPlot[mc,
  Epilog -> {
    MapIndexed[{Text[Style[#1, 10, Gray],
        Reverse[#2 - {.5, .5}]]} &,
     Reverse[mc],
     {2}]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0],
 Colorize[mc]
 ]
```

[image: labeled]

## Update

Thanks to stefan's [amazing detective work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27601/61), I've got a way to list the colors, although this isn't available until you run `Colorize` once or set up the colors another way first:

```
colorizeColors[n_] := 
 Part[RGBColor[N@#1/256, N@#2/256, N@#3/256] & @@ 
     Image`ColorOperationsDump`hashcolor[#1] & /@ Range[1, 100], n]
Graphics[Table[{colorizeColors[x], Rectangle[{x, 0}, {x + 1, 1}], 
   White, Text[x, {x + 0.5, -.5}]}, {x, 1, 30}], Background -> Black, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: colorize legend]

Comment: Whohoo!! That looks just amazing!! Wow. Nice job @cormullion :)

Comment: @stefan it's all your fault :)

Comment: I found out how to initialize the internal data structures as well...see my update :) That's what I call a good start of a day.

Comment: @stefan yes you've lifted up a rock and looked at the strange things crawling around underneath! :)

Comment: If you wanted to plot a graphic like in your update, you could've just `GraphicsRow[Colorize /@ (Table[#, {10}, {10}] & /@ Range[30]), 
 ImageSize -> 1000]` -- would've been easier :)

Comment: @Pickett well, yes, but where's the fun :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**How does Colorize work**

*Colorize* does use *DarkRainbow* as a default color scheme.

What Colorize does first is setting up a hashtable with RGB values from DarkRainbow through DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`

The next operation is setting up a list of indices from the original image, iterating through the internal hash-table to fill a list of color triplets and call an internal mapping function, to join it all together.

I'll show here an example for your result from your *MorphologicalComponents*.

1) create the indices table

```
indices = Cases[Tally[Flatten[mc]][[All, 1]], _?Positive]
```

2) allocate a color list

```
colors = ConstantArray[0, {Max[0, indices], 3}]
```

3) fill the colors list with the hashcolor values

```
((colors[[#]] = Quiet[Image`ColorOperationsDump`hashcolor[#1]]) &) /@ indices;
```

4) join it all together to create an image

```
Image[Image`ColorOperationsDump`mapFunc2D1[mc, colors, indices],
    Byte, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

[image]

There is one problem with this approach. I didn't find out, how the internal hash-table is generated with the values from *DarkRainbow*. What that means is, that if my approach should succeed, there must've been an execution of *Colorize* before.

Agreed, that setting up the internal hash-table is a critical step in the coloring process of *Colorize*, it does by all means solve your legend problem.

**Update: Setting up the internal hash-table**

I wrote before that I couldn't find out how the internal hash-table was generated. Well, now I know how:

*Caution!* This makes heavy use of undocumented functionality and may be deprecated.

The internal data-structures are set up from the first time any function is called with *Colorize* and/or *HighlighImage* functionality.

What they do is, they call but do not evaluate them. This seems to be enough in order to initialize the internal data structures, they just construct the object.

```
System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[Colorize], 
    Hold[Colorize, HighlightImage, 
        Image`ColorOperationsDump`colorspaceToColor, 
        Image`ColorOperationsDump`colorToColorspace], 
        "ImageProcessing`ColorOpsColorize`"
]
```

So if you evaluate this code block everything else I described works just perfectly.

**Update 2: Cleaner Initialisation**

Although the above code block works I didn't like it. There must be another way to initialise the internal data-structures for `Colorize`. Something that does not rely on undocumented functionality which may change in future versions.

It seems to me that a load of Mathematica implementation is loaded from a dump file, the first time it gets used.

Let's check that for `Colorize`:

```
ClearAttributes[Colorize, ReadProtected]
Information[Colorize]
```

This sequence yields the same code that I listed above. Obviously this is the initialisation sequence specific for `Colorize` (and `HighlighImage`).

In C++/Java there is something called a Constructor. So my question was is there a way to avoid the above ugly code block and simply initialize the `Colorize` functionality prior any usage, meaning calling a Constructor.

Actually it is. *Evaluate*!

What this means is. You can completely replace the above System`Dump sequence with a simple call to `Evaluate` in order to initialise the internal data-structures:

```
Evaluate[Colorize]; (*construct the object and initialise internal data-structures*)
```

Done. As long as WRI continues with their *load on demand* paradigm this will hold true. Btw. this works on version 8 as well.

Comment: More complicated than I thought! Thanks, will experiment... (+1)

Comment: Cheers :) I tried to find out the hash-table generation as well, but then my notebook crashed several times. I'm working here from linux. Maybe someone else on another platform, with more ram, has more luck.

Comment: The `Evaluate` is not needed, just `Colorize;` will trigger the autoload.

Comment: @SimonWoods yes indeed, but does it also held the attributes held unevaluated. i wasn't sure about that. that's why i encapsulated it inside an `Evaluate`

Comment: Actually ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`hashcolor`` has nothing to do with the `"DarkRainbow"` color scheme: it's implementation is based on `Hash` as can be seen from its definition: `Compile[{{i, _Integer}}, 30 + IntegerDigits[Hash[i], 200, 3]]` (checked with *Mathematica* 8.0.4).