# How to nicely label the colors in Colorize?

Tags: image-processing, color, legending

I have an image segmentation and I'd like to label with a `SwatchLegend[]`. Here's a MWE:

```
SwatchLegend[Colorize[ImageData[Rasterize@Graphics@Annulus[], "Bit"]], {"0", "1"}]
```

The second example from the `Colorize` reference page:

```
cols = Range[Max[labels] + 1];
Legended[Colorize[labels], 
SwatchLegend[Map[RGBColor, ImageData[Colorize[{cols}]][[1]]], cols]]
```

[image: example]

Is there a solution that doesn't entail manually extracting the colors? How would one label the color regions with callouts or other labeling techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way?

```
Legended[
 Colorize[ImageData[Binarize[Rasterize@Graphics@Annulus[]]]],
 SwatchLegend[
  Map[RGBColor, ImageData[Colorize[{{0, 1}}]][[1]]], {"0", "1"}]
 ]
```

[image]

I think `Colorize` expects a rank-two array of integers for two-dimensional images. `Colorize` is typically used as postprocessor of `MorphologicalComponents` and that returns precisely such matrices. Your `ImageData` was a of rank 3, the lowest level being for the color channels. So that might have provoked Mathematica to assume the image were 3D.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to avoid, but I think it might be the only way :(

Answer (score 1):

Using Stefan's answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27587):

```
Colorize; (* force autoloading *)

img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6aAs.png"]
```

[image: test image]

```
labels = MorphologicalComponents[img];
ll = Select[Union[Flatten[labels]], Positive];

cols = RGBColor[Image`ColorOperationsDump`hashcolor[#]/255] & /@ ll;

Legended[Colorize[labels, ImageSize -> Medium], SwatchLegend[cols, ll]]
```

[image: colorization with legends]